# In nesC can command AMSend.send and event Receive.receive work at the same time?

Tags: c, tinyos, nesc

Although i used interface PacketAcknowledgements,i still found i can't guarantee the communication between within one hop... In my experiment,i only use two motes,every 1 second each node send one packet to the other,then i discovered the command AMsend.send can always been called successfully but event Receive.receive is **not** always successfully been signaled...do they conflict to each other? if the command send can preempt the event receive,what can i do to deal with it?Thank you very much...

the file RadioCountToLedsC.nc is as followed:

```
module RadioCountToLedsC @safe() {
  uses {
    interface Leds;
    interface Boot;
    interface Receive;
    interface AMSend;
    interface Timer<TMilli> as MilliTimer;
    interface SplitControl as AMControl;
    interface Packet;
    interface PacketAcknowledgements;
    interface AMPacket;
  }
}
implementation {

  message_t  packet;

  bool locked = FALSE;
  uint16_t counter = 0;

  event void Boot.booted() {
    dbg("Boot","Application booted.\n");
    call AMControl.start();
  }
task void senddatatask()
{
      counter++;
    if (locked==TRUE) {
      return;
    }
    else {
              radio_count_msg_t* rcm = (radio_count_msg_t*)call Packet.getPayload(&packet, sizeof(radio_count_msg_t));
        if (rcm == NULL) {
    return;
          }

        rcm->counter = counter;
        call PacketAcknowledgements.requestAck(&packet);
        if (call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(radio_count_msg_t)) == SUCCESS) {

    locked = TRUE;
        }
      }
}
  event void AMControl.startDone(error_t err) {
    if (err == SUCCESS) {
            call MilliTimer.startPeriodic(1000);

    }
    else {
      call AMControl.start();
    }
  }

  event void AMControl.stopDone(error_t err) {
    // do nothing
  }

  event void MilliTimer.fired() {
    post senddatatask();
  }

  event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* bufPtr, 
                   void* payload, uint8_t len) {
    if (len != sizeof(radio_count_msg_t)) {return bufPtr;}
    else {
      radio_count_msg_t* rcm = (radio_count_msg_t*)payload;
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "Received packet of counter %u.\n", rcm->counter);

      return bufPtr;
    }
  }

  event void AMSend.sendDone(message_t* bufPtr, error_t error) {
    if(&packet == bufPtr && call PacketAcknowledgements.wasAcked(bufPtr)==SUCCESS){
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "packet %u sent.\n", counter); 
        locked = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "NOT ACKED!\n");
    }
    //locked = FALSE;
  }

}
```

Comment: How often do you not get a receive event? What motes are you using, how far apart are they? What environment are you in? This may just be a result of normal interference, collisions etc. and nothing to do with your code. PS [some discussion of preemption in TinyOS on the mailing list](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=interrupt+site%3Amail.millennium.berkeley.edu%2Fpipermail%2Ftinyos-help)

Comment: about every 10 second will a packet not receive...i use TOSSIM for simulation and you know the mote can only be Micaz...P.S when i let one mote only receive and the other mote only send ,it seems that there will be NO packet lost...

Comment: I think you need more information in your question. It's not clear that you're doing a simulation with TOSSIM. Are you feeding in a noise trace? What are your gain and threshold CCA values, what transmit power are you using? How big are the packets you're transmitting? It sounds like the dropped packets are due to interference and/or noise, which is normal. You should be able to debug this with TOSSIM, e.g. using debug statements. In real life, signals can collide or fade. If dropped packets are important your protocol should include the ability to re-try sending if a packet is not ACKed.

Comment: Thank you very much !  i will try to use acks.